# Issue while stacking 2 pictures with subfigure latex package

Tags: floats

I'd like to stack two figures too, while using the subfigure package. It kinda works, excepts that the result is spread all over the place:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering   
\subfigure[Travertines pH measurements]{\label{fig:ph_trav}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph_travertine/pH_Paper_trav.eps}}
\\
\subfigure[Indiana limestones pH measurements]{\label{fig:ph_IL} \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph_IL/pH_Paper_IL}}
\caption{pH measurements for the Tavertines and Indiana limestone experiments. All measures have been done on sub-samples of the fluid before ICP-MS analysis. The hydrolysis of the carbonate ion generates alkalinity which increases the acid-buffering capacity of the reactant solution. Therefore, carbonate dissolution via increased \ce{CaCO3} solubility leads to the generation of carbonate ions and elevates the pH.}
\label{fig:pH}
\end{figure}
```

I am getting kinda lost at this point :)

Best, 
Flo

Comment: With the information you provided so far, the issue is unfortunately not reproducible. Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the same youtput you get.

Comment: Does the issue still occur if you use `example-image` instead of your image files? Do your image files contain a large white boder?

Comment: Since you seem to use the `subfigure` package: This package is deprecated. Please switch to either `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.